# How to save pdf to Aws s3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, pdfbox, java-io

I am using PDFbox to merge two pdf files in my code, then I want to store the resultant (merged file) into AWS s3 bucket.
I was trying storing the pdf file to s3 directly without saving locally in my system, but I am not able to figure out any way to do it.

My code to merge two pdf-

```
PDFMergerUtility pdfMergerUtility = new PDFMergerUtility();
String FinalFileName= "Merged.pdf";

pdfMergerUtility.setDestinationFileName(FinalFileName);
pdfMergerUtility.addSource(FileOne);
pdfMergerUtility.addSource(FileTwo);
pdfMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());

//To upload over s3 
String fileNameIWantInS3 = "myfile.pdf";
s3.putObject(BucketName, fileNameIWantInS3, ??); //Stuck here
```

I don't want to make a file over my server instead I want to put it on s3 directly, how can I modify this code to upload `Merged.pdf` to s3 bucket.
Above code is just a part where I am stuck. FileOne and FileTwo I have created using `File.createTempFile`.

Entire idea is to merge two files and put the final file over s3 without making a physical copy of  that over the server! Please help.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51245535/is-it-possible-to-write-to-s3-via-a-stream-using-s3-java-sdk

Answer (score 0):

to upload the file you need to pass the byte array or input stream, the following use byte array:

```
public void saveFileToS3(String yourBucketName,String pathAws, String folderName) {
    PDFMergerUtility pdfMergerUtility = new PDFMergerUtility();
    String FinalFileName= "Merged.pdf";

    pdfMergerUtility.setDestinationFileName(FinalFileName);
    pdfMergerUtility.addSource(FileOne);
    pdfMergerUtility.addSource(FileTwo);         
    pdfMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    pdfMergerUtility.setDestinationStream(byteArrayOutputStream);  
    AmazonS3 s3Client = AwsUtil.s3Authentication();
    PutObjectRequest objectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
      .bucket(yourBucketName)
      .key(folderName+"/"+pathAws)//pathAws: path on S3 where the file will be saved
      .build();
    //convert it into a byte array
    byte[] pdfBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()  
    CompletableFuture<PutObjectResponse> future = 
    s3Client.putObject(objectRequest,AsyncRequestBody.fromBytes(pdfBytes));
    future.whenComplete((resp, err) -> {
      try {
        if (resp != null) {
          System.out.println("Object uploaded. Details: " + resp);
        } else {
          err.printStackTrace();
        }
      } finally {
        s3Client.close();
      }
    });    
    future.join();   
}
```

Comment: what is "PDFDocument" I have not created the object of PDDocument in my code can you please suggest me based on my code?

Comment: i updated code by including your code and added new line to convert to byte stream `pdfMergerUtility.setDestinationStream(byteArrayOutputStream);`